# Block outgoing connection to a specific ip address in Mac OSx

Tags: mac, ip, blocking

I am trying to block outgoing connection to a specific IP address (I don't know the domain name). Simple adding that IP address to hosts file is not working as I don't have a domain name to pair it against

I am tring to avoid having to install a third party software like Little Snitch. I already have tcpblock installed, but it only blocks it when given the application name.

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X contains two firewall packages: `pf` was recently added and is now preferred, and `ipfw` has been around a long time and is now deprecated.

You can check in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` to make sure the package you like is being started at boot, and then you can check the man pages for those tools to see how to write the rule you need, and what file that rule needs to go in.

There may be third party tools that give you a GUI to help you do this, but I haven't gone looking for them.